# System.windows and system.windows.forms

Tags: c#, .net

In my application I have both System.Windows(WindowsBase) and System.Windows.Forms assemblies.  I have to use System.Windows.Application.

But application is picking up the Application class from System.Windows.Forms instead.

I specified reference System.Windows; in code, but application is still picking up the Application class from System.Windows.Forms.

Can you please help me how to refer to the "Application" class from System.Windows.

Comment: What are you trying to do? is your application a winforms application or a WPF application? meaning what is the initial object where the `Main` method is defined? `System.Windows.Application.Current` is going to be null in a winforms app.

Answer (score 1):

use the fully qualified name like below

```
System.Windows.Application app = new System.Windows.Application();
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the reference to System.Windows.Forms, or else specify which you are using when you use it.

i.e.

```
System.Windows.MessageBox mb = new System.Windows.MessageBox();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have identical class names you need to fully qualify at least one of them with their namespace prefix.

Chances are you added a `using` directive to one of your code files like the following:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

If this is a WPF application you probably do not want to ever add a using directive to `System.Windows.Forms`.  The same goes the opposite way if you are using a Windows Forms application.

For example, let's say you have the following code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

Application myApp = new Application(); // this would throw a compile-time ambiguity error!
```

On the other hand you could do this:

```
using System.Windows;

...

Application myApp = new Application();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying back.  As per your suggestion, I tried to use fully qualified name.  But I didnt find "Application" under System.Windows.   looked at WindowsBase assembly and I didnt see System.Windows.Application.  Which library/assembly can I find it?  I thought it is WindowsBase.

Comment: Google the fully qualified class name "System.Windows.Application" and the MSDN reference page will tell you the name of the assembly DLL.

Comment: Thank you.  I am able to resolve that issue.  I am using wrong dll.  Now when I trying to get "Stream" from with the following code " Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;" .. getting the following error message.  What does this error mean "Error 4 The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IQueryAmbient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. test.cs 72 17 TestSolution
"

Comment: Ok found this issue.  Have to add System.xaml dll.  Thanks everyone for all your help.